# What is the Difference Between x:Key, x:Name, and x:UID in a DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, key, difference, uid

I am trying to create dynamic tabs in WPF, and I'm trying to write a content template that will only apply to some tab items. I want to be able to create an identifier for the content template so that I can reference it in the code behind, and so that I can selectively apply it to only some tabs in a single TabControl. However, I am confused about these three different xaml identifiers. What is the difference, and which one is best for my purposes?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The 'x:' specifies the namespace, which would in your case most likely be "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" You will see the alias declared at the top of your Window.Xaml file.  x:Key, x:Name, etc are all directives in that namespace.

In contrast, the 'Name' attribute (without the x:) is a dependency property declared in the FrameworkElement class.

**x:Key**

Uniquely identifies elements that are created and referenced in a XAML-defined dictionary. Adding an x:Key value to a XAML object element is the most common way to identify a resource in a resource dictionary, for example in a WPF ResourceDictionary.

**x:Name**

Uniquely identifies XAML-defined elements in a XAML namescope. XAML namescopes and their uniqueness models can be applied to the instantiated objects, when frameworks provide APIs or implement behaviors that access the XAML-created object graph at run time.

**x:Uid**

Provides a unique identifier for markup elements. In many scenarios, this unique identifier is used by XAML localization processes and tools.

**Notes**

I have only seen **x:Uid** when a app must support different languages with a resource dictionary.

For the other two (x:Key and x:Name), a basic rule of thumb is to use **x:Name** for Framework elements and **x:Key** for styles, templates, and so on.  So for your question, if you are naming a template itself, you would use the **x:Key** directive.  Controls declared within the template would use the **x:Name** directive.

A complete list of all Xaml directives is given at [Xaml Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to apply the template to all the tabs in your page, you can use **x:Type**, but if you want to apply it to few tabs and not to all the tabs you can use **x:Key**.

Generally you will use **x:Key** when you want to use it as StaticResource in your xaml file. You will provide **x:Name** to a control or template when you want to refer it in your code-behind. I have never used X:Uid, but this is what MSDN says,

> Use x:Uid to identify an object element in your XAML. Typically this
>   object element is an  instance of a control class or other element
>   that is displayed in a UI. The relationship  between the string you
>   use in x:Uid and the strings you use in a resources file is that the
>   resource file strings are the x:Uid followed by a dot (.) and then by
>   the name of a specific  property of the element that's being
>   localized.