# UWP VisualStateManager change number of columns ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Ive got simple `ListView` that represents a grid and i want to switch number of columns depending on `Window Width`. 
Here is the code for `ListView`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Dictionary.xaml"/>
</Page.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="lvCurrencyList" />
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="lvCurrencyList.HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CurrencyListHeaderTemplate}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="lvCurrencyList.HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CompactCurrencyListHeaderTemplate}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And here is the code for `HeaderTemplate` in `Dictionary.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="CurrencyListHeaderTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Here goes the content-->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Name="CompactCurrencyListHeaderTemplate">
    <Grid Background="#e6e6e6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Here goes the content-->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But that code doesent work for me

Comment: It should be <DataTemplate x:Key="CurrencyListHeaderTemplate"> instead x:Name. Hope it works..

Comment: I tested your code in my side and it works well. So could you share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in the `VisualStateManager` definition, it was in wrong location. Ive added it into children of a `Page.Grid`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined DataTemplate Resource incorrectly. It should be

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CurrencyListHeaderTemplate"> instead x:Name.
```

Have look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935688/what-is-the-difference-between-xkey-xname-and-xuid-in-a-datatemplate-in-wpf) for differnce between x:key and x:name

Comment: This wont help me. If i add a new line to `ListView` with  `HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CompactCurrencyListHeaderTemplate}"` without changing x:Name to x:Key, that will add template as expected. But This wont work in `VisualStateManager` even with `x:Key`

Comment: WinRT doesn't support TemplateBinding within a style, isnt it?

Comment: Did you write datatemplate definitions inside page.resources?

Comment: No, they in a separate file.
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Dictionary.xaml"/>
    </Page.Resources>

And now i try to change just `Background` property of a list, this wont work too ^(